# Can't get shipping street & city

Tags: magento2.4

I've created a custom module to get order data to be used into tracking code in success page.
I got all data phone, total country .. etc except the street and city !
I don't know what's the problem, below my model code :

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Nectar\Google\Block;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Success extends Template
{
    /** @var Session */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getGrandTotal()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }
    
    public function getEmail()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getCustomerEmail();
    }
    
    public function getFirst()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getCustomerFirstname();
    }
    
    public function getLast()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        return $order->getCustomerLastname();
    }
    
    public function getMobile()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $telephone = $order->getShippingAddress();
        return $telephone->getTelephone();
    }
    
    public function getStreet()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $street = $order->getShippingAddress();
        return $street->getStreet();
    }
    
    public function getCity()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $city = $order->getShippingAddress();
        return $city->getCity();
    }
    
    public function getCountry()
    {
        $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $country = $order->getShippingAddress();
        return $country->getCountryId();
    }

}
```

Could you please advise.

Comment: 1. You should understand that this code will not work properly for virtual orders. 2.  `getStreet` is array. 3. I don't believe that you can get telephone and cannot get the city. 4. Please also provide the fragment of use missing data.

Comment: Hi Victor, I already get telephone ! Okay how I could get the other data.

Comment: I've used below code to get the result of each function in phtml
$country = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('\Nectar\Google\Block\Success')->getCountry();

Comment: Looks like you still don't understand how Magento works and how you should use it. It's a bad practice at all create new block for each request. You should use your block in layout with your template and use methods like `$block->getCountry()`. I've asked about fields like city and using of, but you provide example with country. It's really difficult to help when people are not try to read advices and questions.

Comment: I'm creating block because I'm using these functions in another template not the one of same module.
Second thing I've provided you just an example for country which mean I'm using the same thing for other functions.
Finally you don't have to help if you want.